Movie about a man that can talk to dogs and read books just by touching them
The movie takes place in an urban setting (like those tall building where you need to pull the fire escape ladder down to get to your flat). 
The movie plot is as follows: A man finds a green rock, which gives him the the following powers:

communicating with dogs
reading by osmosis
I think it also gives him strength (not sure about this). 

I know a lot of dogs follow him (there are a lot of dogs walking the road, since it is urban). He can communicate with them, and when he touches a book, he finished reading it already without even opening it? Very old movie, English, Hollywood
(I watched it about the same time BLANKMAN came out) this was in in the 1990's.

The film is called Meteor Man. He can absorb a books content and telepath with dogs.

One night Jefferson Reed gets hit in the chest by a souped-up chunk of
  meteor. So he can fly, but he's scared of heights. He can master the
  information in any book ... for about fifteen minutes. Now his friends
  and family want him to protect their community from the dreaded Golden
  Lords.


Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it is the correct answer to your question.
